# how to use lock in Julia

Tags: julia, synchronized

I'm working with Julia. The IDE is Juno.

If I'm right, `@async` can generate a task, it's just like a thread.
So we can do this:

```
@async begin
   # do something1
end
@async begin
   # do something2
end
```

Now, I need to lock a thread. For example, `do something1` is to push message to a list and `do something2` is to pop message from the same list.

It's like `synchronized` in Java.

what is `synchronized` in julia?

Comment: Also see: [Reactive.jl](http://julialang.org/Reactive.jl/#signals) (and [Interactive.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Interact.jl))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also a [`@sync`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/parallel/?highlight=%40sync#Base.@sync) macro:

> help?> @sync
>
> Wait until all dynamically-enclosed uses of @async, @spawn, @spawnat
>   and   @parallel are complete. All exceptions thrown by enclosed async
>   operations   are collected and thrown as a CompositeException.

```rb
@sync @async begin
   # do something1
end

@sync begin
    # some code    
    @async begin
        # do something2
    end
    @async # do something 3
end
```

Answer (score 4):

To keep a block mutex:

```
mutex = RemoteRef()

@async begin
   put!(mutex, true)
   # do something1
   take!(mutex)
end
@async begin
   put!(mutex, true)
   # do something2
   take!(mutex)
end
```